# scanf EOF and Loops

Tags: c, eof

This is a school assignment but I cannot get my loop to work.  We have to use scanf and terminate the loop when an EOF is inputted.  This is the part of the code that is the problem:

```
{int
 main(void){
   char str[MAX];

   while(scanf("%s", str) != EOF)
   {
     printf("\nEnter a String: ");
     scanf("%s", str);  
     two_ele_subs(str);
   }


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what actually happens when your run that code?

Comment: And you can't input `EOF` it's not a character.

Comment: No `MAX`, no control user did nor enter `MAX` or more characters, no `#include <stdio.h>`.  "cannot get my loop to work" is not specific enough.

Comment: Why do you have `{` before `int main`?

Comment: You're calling `scanf` twice each time through the loop -- once in the `while` statement, where you just check for EOF and discard what the user typed, and again after the prompt. So it's waiting for an extra input BEFORE each prompt.

Comment: Well this isn't my entire code, just a portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sscanf returns the number of read variables, that in your case is only one, or EOF (ie: -1) in case of end of file. So I suggest you to use a different approach, like in the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX  100

int main(void){
   char str[MAX];
   int retVal;

   printf("\nEnter a String: ");
   while((retVal = scanf("%s", str)) == 1 || retVal != EOF)
   {
     printf("\nEnter a String: ");
     two_ele_subs(str);
   }
   return 0;
}
```